# Finding the intersection of two circles

Tags: asymptote, intersections

I am attempting to use pair[] intersectionpoints to find and label the intersection points of the circles defined by path h and path g. Thanks for the help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}

\begin{asypicture}{name=Label}
import olympiad;
size(7cm);
import graph;
pair A=(0,0);
dot(A);
label("$A$",A,W);
pair C=A+18dir(40);
dot(C);
label("$C$",C,N);
pair D=A+16dir(20);
dot(D);
label("$D$",D,SE);
pair e=A+9dir(20);
dot(e);
label("$E$",e,NE);
pair F=A+8dir(40);
dot(F);
label("$F$",F,W);
path g = circle(A,12);
draw(g);
path h = circumcircle(F,D,C);
pair[] intersectionpoints(path g, path h);
dot(point([0]);
dot(point([1]);
draw(A--C);
draw(A--D);
pair O=circumcenter(F,D,C); // olympiad - circumcenter
dot(O);
label("$O$",O,S);
draw(circumcircle(F,D,C)); // olympiad - circumcircle
\end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It think there shouldn't be a `\begin{asy}` after `\begin{asypicture}{name=Label}` and `\end{asy}` should be `\end{asypicture}`.

Comment: Thanks Marmot, I've made those edits. Still hasn't solved the problem of plotting the intersections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After downloading `opympiad.asy` from [this web site](https://math.berkeley.edu/~monks/images/olympiad.asy), it was easy. I guess you have misinterpreted the statement in [this nice tutorial](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) a bit, so I adjusted `pair[] intersectionpoints(path g, path h);` a bit and removed other syntax errors to get

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}

\begin{asypicture}{name=Label}
import olympiad;
size(7cm);
import graph;
pair A=(0,0);
dot(A);
label("$A$",A,W);
pair C=A+18*dir(40);
dot(C);
label("$C$",C,N);
pair D=A+16*dir(20);
dot(D);
label("$D$",D,SE);
pair e=A+9*dir(20);
dot(e);
label("$E$",e,NE);
pair F=A+8*dir(40);
dot(F);
label("$F$",F,W);
path g = circle(A,12);
draw(g);
path h = circumcircle(F,D,C);
pair[] ipoints = intersectionpoints(g,h);
dot(ipoints[0]);
dot(ipoints[1]);
draw(A--C);
draw(A--D);
pair O=circumcenter(F,D,C); // olympiad - circumcenter
dot(O);
label("$O$",O,S);
draw(h); // olympiad - circumcircle
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just to mention that `geometry.asy` (included with Asymptote) provides a large number of plane geometry routines (triangle, circle, ellipse, etc) and appropriate structures. For example, if `C` is a circle, `C.C` is the center while `C.r` is the radius. 
Here a copy/paste of marmot answer with `geometry.asy` package.

```
    import geometry;
    point A=(0,0);
    dot(A);
    label("$A$",A,W);
    point C=A+18*dir(40);
    dot(C);
    label("$C$",C,N);
    point D=A+16*dir(20);
    dot(D);
    label("$D$",D,SE);
    point e=A+9*dir(20);
    dot(e);
    label("$E$",e,NE);
    point F=A+8*dir(40);
    dot(F);
    label("$F$",F,W);
    circle g = circle(A,12);
    draw(g);
    circle h = circle(F,D,C);
    pair[] ipoints = intersectionpoints(g,h);
    dot(ipoints[0]);
    dot(ipoints[1]);
    draw(A--C);
    draw(A--D);
    point O=h.C; // circle is a structure, h.C the center, h.r the radius
    label("$r\approx$"+string(h.r,4),(18,1));
    dot(O);
    label("$O$",O,S);
    draw(h);
```

and almost the same picture
[image]